CIP-30 address format to addr1 style for db-sync
I'm a bit lost. I've got the https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-connect-with-wallet/tree/main working and can get the used addresses from a wallet. I would like to use those to query db-sync. There seems to be conversion problem as the library returns raw addresses (?!?) and in db-sync 'addr1...' style addresses are used.
Is there any way to convert them or use the raw addresses to query db-sync?
Thanks!

Most of the tables that hold addresses have separate columns for the raw address and the Bech32 encoding.
Maybe there are some hints here: https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/interesting-queries.md

Thanks for the replay. Is it possible that this page isn't up to date? In their examples the table 'tx_out' containers an raw_address field, but not in the latest db_sync?

Some changes were made recently and some more have been proposed. See https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/issues/1835

Thank youi for the hints! Getting there.

I switched to https://github.com/MeshJS/mesh which solves the problem.
