Address format help CIP-30 to db-sync
could anybody help me figure out how to use the "hex-encoded bytes format" addresses (used addresses) from CIP-30 to query db-sync table tx_out? Are there good examples on how to decode/encode them in a postgres query?

This is very similar to: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/cip-30-address-format-to-addr1-style-for-db-sync/12636?noredirect=1#comment8062_12636

https://github.com/MeshJS/mesh solved my problem.

https://github.com/MeshJS/mesh solved my problem by returning addresses already in the 'addr....' format.
